# How to find tags that combine letters, symbol and numbers from HTML sources?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Examples of HTML source is as follows.

I don't need "stickthread" items, but I only need to find all or select all "normalthread" items.

```
<table summary="idea_31"
 <tbody id="stickthread_234234">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234235">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234127">
 <tbody id="stickthread_232634">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234202">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234116">
  <script type="text/javascript">
 <tbody id="normalthread_213551">
 <tbody id="normalthread_223551">
 <tbody id="normalthread_214251">
 <tbody id="normalthread_213761">
 <tbody id="normalthread_210951">
 <tbody id="normalthread_221151">
 <tbody id="normalthread_295851">
 <tbody id="normalthread_222351">
 <tbody id="normalthread_217778">
 <tbody id="normalthread_215588">
 <tbody id="normalthread_215331">
</table>
```

> xpath //table[@summary="idea_31"]/tbody

Assuming I use xpath, I can specify the following goals, but I'm at a loss how to find this combination after tbody (normalthread + _ + numbers).

Suppose I use 'BeautifulSoup' or 'parsel' for html parser and tell me how.
Thank you.

Comment: So, do you want to find all `<tbody>` where `id=` begins with `normalthread_` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, that's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `tbody[id^="normalthread_"]` (select all `<tbody>` where `id=` begins with "normalthread_"):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<table summary="idea_31">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234234">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234235">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234127">
 <tbody id="stickthread_232634">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234202">
 <tbody id="stickthread_234116">
 <tbody id="normalthread_213551">
 <tbody id="normalthread_223551">
 <tbody id="normalthread_214251">
 <tbody id="normalthread_213761">
 <tbody id="normalthread_210951">
 <tbody id="normalthread_221151">
 <tbody id="normalthread_295851">
 <tbody id="normalthread_222351">
 <tbody id="normalthread_217778">
 <tbody id="normalthread_215588">
 <tbody id="normalthread_215331">
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
for tbody in soup.select('tbody[id^="normalthread_"]'):
    print(tbody["id"])
```

Prints:

```
normalthread_223551
normalthread_214251
normalthread_213761
normalthread_210951
normalthread_221151
normalthread_295851
normalthread_222351
normalthread_217778
normalthread_215588
normalthread_215331
```